# Toggle the case of the character under cursor in vim

Tags: vim

When adding a prefix to a camel case variable, I usually need to Capitalize the (now second) word of the identifier. For example, when `logGroup` becomes `localLogGroup`, `log` becomes `Log`.

I am looking for a way to toggle the case of the current character (the one highlighted by the cursor) in vim.

The point is toggling the case without selecting the character - same way as `x` deletes it. I simply want to toggle its case.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: you mean something like `~` ? see `:h ~` It indeed waits for a motion, but with `~~` it just toggles the current character and moves the cursor to the right. Is the movement to the right what you want to avoid?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For changing case of character under cursor, you can use `~`. More at `:help ~`.

`~` can also be made as a operator when `top` is set. More at `:help top`.